# docker faild to restore postgres backup

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to create and restore postgres backup using docker.
the docker failed to do it and gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:11

ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB dbName

COPY backup.backup /
COPY initdb.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

initdb.sh:

```
pg_restore --username=postgres --create --exit-on-error --verbose --dbname=dbName backup.backup
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
image: postgres:11
expose:
  - "5432"
ports:
  - "15432:5432"
volumes:
  - dock-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
environment:
  - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= postgres
  - POSTGRES_DB= dbName


volumes:
  dock-volume:
```

I tried to add the environment variables to docker-compose.yml but it doesnt help..

Answer (score 0):

You should not create a `Dockerfile` for the Postgres because you already have the definition in your `Dockercompose` file. The variables that you define under `environment` are visible inside Postgres. If you want to have a backup and make sure that is running when you initialize you can do:

```
volumes:
  - ~/Downloads/data/my_buckup.psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/stage.sql
```

Then when Postgres initialize this script will be run. You can see the documentation [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) under the section `How to extend this image`

I hope it makes sense